# Eclipse ADT no fragment_main.xml or activity_main.xml files

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

I'm trying to learn how to program android applications. I've been looking at the basic tutorials published by Google on the following  link: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html
It states that I should open the fragment_main.xml file, however this file does not exist. Nor does the activity_main.xml file. Please advise as to what I should do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create them yourself Inside res>layouts by right click new>xml

Answer (score -1):

There is a workaround for it ahead of updates to the official tutorial pages, which the community seems to agree are needed.  See [Issue 67421](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=67421) for the full story, but the workaround comes from [torway.h...@gmail.com](https://code.google.com/u/104194421438760836201/) therein:

> [Y]ou can effectively work around this issue by selecting "Blank activity with Fragment" in the tutorial instead of just "Blank Activity" - doing so will create the file fragment_main.xml in res/layout/ which is needed to continue following the steps.